# trouble getting 'createTimeStamp' from active directory

Tags: c#, active-directory

I'm trying to get the "createTimeStamp" from an Active Directory instance. The data is stored in UTC Coded Time. I've tried everything I can think of and scoured the internet for several days, but have not been able to get this field. The error I get with the code below is an 'index out of range' exception. When I look at the field in the active directory server, everything is there. I know my LDAP string is correct because I can get everything else just fine. Any thoughts?

```
    DateTime dateCreated = new DateTime();
                            string strDateCreated = "";
                            try
                            {
                                dateCreated = (DateTime)result.Properties["createTimeStamp"][0];
                                long ticks4 = new DateTime(1601, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0).ToLocalTime().Ticks;
                                dateCreated = new DateTime(ticks4 + dateCreated.ToLocalTime().Ticks);
                                strDateCreated = dateCreated.ToString();
                            }
                            catch
                            {
                                strDateCreated = "NULL";
                            }
```

Comment: Did you add the createTimeStamp property to the PropertiesToLoad collection?

Comment: Genius! That worked like a charm! Sorry, I'm a total n00b to AD. Thanks!